# How to set INPUT relative to Doxyfile?

Tags: git, doxygen

I have a git repository for my project, and I'd like to add a `Doxyfile` in the repo so that anyone working on the project can create a directory on their computer and simply run `doxygen /path/to/the/repo/Doxyfile` from there to fill it with the project's documentation.

I've been looking at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html for a while, but I just can't find how to fill the `INPUT` field to tell doxygen where the files are.

- I can't use absolute paths since I don't know where people will clone the repo on their machine
- I can't use relative paths since they are relative to where the command is run and I don't know where people want to put their documentation

How do I express paths relative to the `Doxyfile` (or maybe to the repo's location since that's the next best thing)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: @albert I'm using version 1.8.17, but if the answer requires upgrading to a newer version, getting my team to install it would not be an issue

Comment: It is just top get a complete picture, upgrading is not necessary for this problem though upgrading to the current version (1.8.20) is in a lot of cases beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no built-in solution for my problem, so far I've come up with this.

In the `Doxyfile`:

```
INPUT = $(DOXYFILE_DIR)/relative/path
```

In a `generate_doxygen.sh` file beside it:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOXYFILE_DIR=`dirname $0`
export DOXYFILE_DIR
doxygen $DOXYFILE_DIR/Doxyfile
```

(But I assume there's a built-in way to do it without an extra file and I've just missed it, since it's such a basic feature while it's the first time I'm creating a `Doxyfile`...)

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen has the possibility to use environment variables in the configuration file, you could use these in a.o. the `INPUT` possibility.
This environment variable can be set by means of en environment variable or when using e.g. CMake you can set this in the generation phase.
Another way is, for CMake, to use placeholders like `@...@` in your default configuration file and during the CMake generation phase substitute these by the path for CMake generation.